# Compile Mustache template using c# library without rendering data and sections

Tags: c#, mustache

Is there a way to "compile" a mustache template using [Stubble](https://github.com/StubbleOrg/Stubble) without inlining all the data? What I mean by compiling is the following:

- given the template `Main`

  ```
  {{ Foo }}
  {{ > SomePartial}}
  {{ #SomeSection }} world {{ /SomeSection }}
  ```
- and partial template `SomePartial`

  ```
  hello
  ```
- I would like to get a following template as a result of some functions calls:

  ```
  {{ Foo }}
  hello
  {{ #SomeSection }} world {{ /SomeSection }}
  ```

If it is not possible with Stubble, I'm open to another library